# AVG function is returning wrong result

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I am trying to get an average from one column in my data set. However, when I test it on excel, the sql result is returning a wrong result.

The table structure is something like this:

```
 ticker_symb   day_sum_eff_dt  cusip     clos_prc  n_clos_prc  DIFF   AVRG
 ASLR           05/17        13799F229     0.234    0.234        0     0
```

This is my code so far:

```
SELECT 
ticker_symb, day_sum_eff_dt, cusip, 
clos_prc, 
n_clos_prc,
      case
       when  clos_prc is null and n_clos_prc is not null 
       then (n_clos_prc - LAG( n_clos_prc ignore nulls) OVER (ORDER BY cusip)) 
       else NULL
       end DIFF,
AVG(DIFF) OVER(PARTITION BY cusip ) AS avrg
FROM (SELECT  
day_sum_eff_dt, cusip,
ticker_symb_cd, 
clos_prc, 
navgen_clos_prc
  case
       when  clos_prc is null and n_clos_prc is not null 
       then (n_clos_prc - LAG( n_clos_prc ignore nulls) OVER (ORDER BY cusip)) 
       else NULL
       end DIFF
        from DAILY_SUMMARY
where
day_sum_eff_dt > sysdate-60
and  (cusip in ( '13799F229'))
order by  cusip, day_sum_eff_dt;
```

The average result given from the DIFF column is *-0.00057993076923076*

but the actual average is *-0.0002949250000*.Not that the results you'll get is the same but this gives an idea of how much the result differs

what could be wrong with the code?

Comment: What are the results of the select in the subquery?

Comment: the results of the DIFF case in the subquery is correct. I have checked it on a smaller sample and the math works on that subquery

Comment: You'll have to supply more information. Data would probably help.

Comment: Do you have NULL prices? (If so, WHY?) Then - how does Excel treat such NULLs? (Hint: it probably treats them as zero in the computation of averages; Oracle simply ignores them). Then: LAG(... IGNORE NULLS) will still produce NULL if there are no non-NULL values preceding the current one. Then: a-b is NULL if a or b is NULL; for this reason, AVG(a-b) is not necessarily the same as AVG(a) - AVG(b). (!!!!!) It would be best if you provided info for a single cusip, and a sequence of perhaps 15 dates and prices, with a few NULL prices if your data allows NULL prices.

Comment: Your query seems broken. You are selecting `ticker_symb` and `n_clos_prc` from a derived table that doesn't contain these columns. Also there is no closing parenthesis for the derived table. So this query can't possibly give any result other than a syntax error.